# How to know wallet name by wallet Address?

Tags: wallet, nami-wallet, cardano-address, api, cardano-api

I am fetching the data of  ADA rate in USD through api(https://studio-api.nmkr.io/v2/GetAdaRates) and I want to fetch the some data of related to wallet like its wallet name, wallet image, wallet current balance, ADA rates in USD . So is there any api for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch the same data but related to wallet"? The rate of ADA in USD is the same for every wallet. Maybe you want to get rate in USD but of other `tokens` instead?

Comment: I am getting the ADA rates from nmkr.io which i am using to get current price fluctuations in rates of ADA.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple API to get data from the Cardano Blockchain, you can use [Koios](https://api.koios.rest/) or [Blockfrost](https://docs.blockfrost.io/). You can use these APIs to get the wallet balance for example.

Cardano wallets don't have a name or an image/icon, therefore you can't get a these from any API.
Unless you're referring to an [Adahandle](https://adahandle.com/), in that case you can look for a native asset from the Adahandle policy in the wallet.